# Compare last text of a TextView with new, updated one, in android home widget using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-widget, textview, android-pendingintent

I've made a simple home screen widget which has two TextView fields and a refresh button. TextViews are loaded from AsyncTask which downloads and parses small XML file. The refresh button calls onUpdate again (using PendingIntent), and eventually AsyncTask again. I have a simple model class XMLValues which can store parsed values from the XML (and which is initialized in the AppWidgetProvider class:

```
public class XmlValues {
private int mFieldValue1;

public int getFieldValue1() {
    return mFieldValue1;
}
public void setFieldValue1(int FieldValue) {
    mFieldValue1 = FieldValue;

private int mFieldValue2;

public int getFieldValue2() {
    return mFieldValue2;
}
public void setFieldValue2(int FieldValue) {
    mFieldValue2 = FieldValue;
}
```

}

In AsyncTask (I pass in it RemoteViews views, int appWidgetID, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) where the XML is downloaded and parsed, the postExecute method looks something like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(XmlValues xv) {
       if (isCancelled()) {
           xv = null;
       }

       views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, xv.getFieldValue1());
       views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, xv.getFieldValue1());
       WidgetManager.updateAppWidget(WidgetID, views);

   }
```

This all works (I load the TextViews with correct values), however I am stuck trying to do the following - since the XML values that I am parsing can potentially change, I would like (for example) to change the color of the TextViews if the new values that come from the new XML are larger then the current ones in the widget. How can I achieve this? I tried looking around but didn't manage to find how to affect the model class object created in the main widget class, from the onPostExecute method from AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static int field where you can store last value:

```
private static int lastValue1 = -1; // you can use other initial value
private static int lastValue2 = -1;
```

You can use it then, for example:

```
if( lastValue1 < xv.getFieldValue1() ) {
  lastValue1 = xv.getFieldValue1();
  views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, xv.getFieldValue1());
}
// the same for second value.
```

Another solution is to store last value in SharedPreferenced.